# linux chmod causing crash

Tags: linux-kernel, chmod

I needed to give write permission to file representing GPIO pins,out of curiosity i taught changing permissions of all files/folders,by mistake instead of doing **chmod 755 *** in the root

I did **chmod 750 *** and the system crashed(doesn't boot) ,although I solved the problem by overwriting the permission using a live cd.I didn't understand what went wrong with chmod 750 *,boot loader is not bothered about any of it ,boot loader simply copies the 1st sector of hard disk and hands over the control to OS.

Is it that the entry code is treated as *others*,or some process may be init needs those permissions to be set??

Comment: If you give people a description of [what your computer actually did](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/problem-report-standard-litany.html) rather than "it crashed", they'll be able to tell you what file/device/directory permissions were the relevant ones.  But people aren't telepathic, and there is wide range of things that "it crashed" could be, at different points in the startup process.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that the permissions on /tmp are still messed up.

My root filesystem on CentOS 5 looks like this:

```
[8:21am][wlynch@apple ~] ls -al /
total 178
drwxr-xr-x  24 root root  4096 Feb  1 20:56 .
drwxr-xr-x  24 root root  4096 Feb  1 20:56 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     0 Feb  1 20:56 .autofsck
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     0 Jan 25 14:55 .autorelabel
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Feb  8 04:02 bin
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  1024 Jan 25 15:21 boot
drwxr-xr-x  11 root root  3700 Feb  6 11:20 dev
drwxr-xr-x 106 root root 12288 Feb  8 04:02 etc
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Jan 25 14:56 home
drwxr-xr-x  11 root root  4096 Jan 31 18:18 lib
drwxr-xr-x   8 root root 12288 Feb  8 04:02 lib64
drwx------   2 root root 16384 Jan 25 08:44 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 May 11  2011 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     0 Feb  1 20:57 misc
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Jan 25 20:01 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     0 Feb  1 20:57 net
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 Jan 25 16:41 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 150 root root     0 Feb  1 14:56 proc
drwxr-x---   7 root root  4096 Feb  6 11:21 root
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 12288 Feb  8 04:02 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jan 25 14:45 selinux
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 May 11  2011 srv
drwxr-xr-x  11 root root     0 Feb  1 14:56 sys
drwxrwxrwt  15 root root  4096 Feb  8 08:20 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  15 root root  4096 Jan 25 14:47 usr
drwxr-xr-x  22 root root  4096 Jan 25 14:51 var
```